# Change in value via object reference not changing in java? please refer below code

Tags: java

```
class Demo {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        A b = a;
        System.out.println(a.x);// 10 As expected
        System.out.println(b.x);// 10 As expected
        a.change();
        System.out.println(a.x);// 10 WHY 10! still. Displays 20 if I remove int
                                // data type under change method.
        System.out.println(b.x);// 10 WHY 10! still.Displays 20 if I remove int
                                // data type under change method.

    }

}

class A {

    int x = 10;

    public void change() {
        int x = 20; // I am delcaring this with int data type
    }

}
```

Comment: `int x = 20;` inside method, create a new local variable with name x.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder `create a new local variable` ? That is actually causing the issue :)

Comment: indeed. As your answer already cleared tht fact.

Comment: Read about [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) in java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: I got it as Creating local variable  wil be inside the local scope to that method only, it wil not over ride the instance variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the method

```
public void change(){
    int x=20; // I am declaring this with int data type
}
```

You are declaring a new variable which is not  the variable `x` at instance level.

Change your method to

```
public void change(){
    this.x=20; // I am declaring this with int data type
}
```